# Edit that corrects a broken piece of code is rejected, while another one suggesting adding a single 'space' is approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I recently edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353099/csrf-token-error-while-requesting-a-json-on-post-reqest/27354947#27354947) in which I corrected the usage of *csrf_token* in [Django](https://Django_%28web_framework%29)'s template, but my edit was rejected, although the original answer didn't use the correct syntax:

[image: Screenshot of the edit]

All three comments left by reviewers are identical and I really don't understand how exactly my edit deviates from the original intent of the post. And probably this shouldn't matter, but the first user *NKN* doesn't even have Django in the list of his/her tags. George has neither.

However, today I saw [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12166096/revisions) (revision #3) and I'm confused now. It's since 2012 and maybe the editing system was different back then.

This was my first edit, so maybe I'm missing something. I just want to learn how should I correctly edit questions/answers.

Comment: That "single-space" edit did not need to be approved, since the editor has more than 2K reputation. I agree that edit is pretty worthless, but the suggestion system is not to blame, only the editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit reviewers are very reluctant to approve edits that seems to change code. Unless they know Django they cannot judge the correctness of that edit.

The reviewers choose to stay on the safe side and rejected your edit. If they are no subject matter expert they better had chosen Skip, as [there is no shame in using skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195).

In these cases you better leave a comment (if you have the privilege) for the OP instead of trying to fix it directly.

Remember to try to fix everything there is to fix, including grammar, spelling and punctuation mistakes.

Answer (score 7):

There is an apples-to-oranges comparison going on here.  Specifically...with the edit you refer to as being 1 space, the user has > 2K reputation, so they're [trusted to do edits without them going to peer review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

As to your edit, I personally would have rejected it as well, simply because as a non-Django professional, I can't be certain if the syntax is right.  If the syntax *is* wrong, then the answer is wrong too, and should be downvoted - and this is one of the rare occasions in which I'd leave a comment explaining why.